# run uwsgi after official nginx container start?

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, uwsgi, docker-entrypoint

I just write a customized container dockerfile including `CMD["uwsgi", "--ini", "uwsgi.ini"]` based on nginx official image

And I see there's a `CMD["nginx", "-g", "daemon off"]` in the end of Dockerfile of this nginx official image.

That should means starting nginx when container starts.
So my `CMD["uwsgi", "--ini", "uwsgi.ini"]` in my dockerfile will overridde it, thus the container will immediately exit.
How should I not override it and make both nginx and uwsgi work?

I'v googled a lot but none of those solutions are based on nginx official image.
Obviously I can run another container just for uwsgi and connect it to nginx container(i.e. the container runned by nginx offcial image), but I think it's troublesome and unnecessary.

[the nginx offcial image here](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` to run multiple processes inside a container by feeding a shell script/wrapper. You should try to refrain from it since that isn't a best practice. Single container should be responsible for managing single process.

However there is a workaround by which you can manage multiple processes inside a container i.e by using a **shell script wrapper** or **supervisor**.
It's there in official docs -
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not docker philosophy to run 2 processes in one container.
This is a commonly accepted one : [officialy](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#decouple-applications), and [through the community](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/447/why-it-is-recommended-to-run-only-one-process-in-a-container)

So you'd rather build a stack, with both a nginx and your application.

Provided you really want or need to do this your way, you can [pipe several command within the CMD instruction](https://serverfault.com/questions/685697/multiple-commands-in-docker-cmd-directive) if you specify the command shell at first... but you can also use a [script](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) here.
Remember that the script will be executed from within your container, so think from a container POV, and not from a host one!